# Identify subgroup of a semidirect product in GAP

Tags: abstract-algebra, gap, semidirect-product

I have created an external semidirect product of two groups $H$ and $K$ in GAP. Now, I want to identify $H$ as a subgroup of this semidirect product, but I am unable to identify $H$. How can I identify $H$ in this semidirect product in GAP? Please help!!! Thank you. Below is the code that I used to construct the semidirect product.

```
gap> H:=DihedralGroup(12);
<pc group of size 12 with 3 generators>
gap> aut:=AutomorphismGroup(H);
<group of size 12 with 3 generators>
gap> inn:=InnerAutomorphismsAutomorphismGroup(aut);
<group with 3 generators>
gap> semi:=SemidirectProduct(inn,H);
<pc group with 5 generators>
```

Now, I want to identify `inn` (InnerAutomorphism group of H) as the subgroup of this semidirect product.

Comment: Could you please add some code which shows how have you constructed it?

Comment: yes sir. I have added the code that i used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The group constructed with  `SemidirectProduct` will have two monomorphisms from the constituents. `Embedding(semi,1)` is the one from `inn`, `Embedding(semi,2)` the one from `H`. Thus its `Image` will be the group you want, and you can also use it to find the elements corresponding to particular inner automorphisms:

```
gap> ea:=Embedding(semi,1);;
gap> Image(ea);
Group([ f1, f2, f2^2 ])
gap> Image(ea,InnerAutomorphism(H,H.1));
f1
```